# Data binding with xsodata on SAP UI5

Tags: json, data-binding, odata, sapui5

I have a backend that runs on SAP HANA, which uses a `xsodata` service to communicate with the frontend (coded with SAP UI5). The `xsodata` service outputs data in the following format:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "type": "music.Music_infoType",
          "uri": "***/odata/music.xsodata/Music_info('10020')"
        },
        "ID": "10020",
        "TITLE": "Music 1"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "type": "music.Music_infoType",
          "uri": "***/odata/music.xsodata/Music_info('10026')"
      },
    "ID": "10026",
    "TITLE": "Music 2"
  }
}
```

In my `manifest.json` file I load this information into a model:

```
"sap.app": {
  ...
  "dataSources": {
    "topmusics": {
        "uri": "/path/to/odata/music.xsodata/Music_info",
        "type": "JSON"
    }
  }
},
"sap.ui5": {
  ...
  "models": {
   "topmusics": {
        "dataSource": "topmusics"
    }
  }
}
```

At the XML view I try to pass a parameter to filter the top 5 musics and load the data to a list. However, since the data doesn't start at the "root" of the file but at "`d/results`" (see the json snippet), I also have to pass this information, which leads me to the following code:

```
<List headerText="Top 5 Musics" 
  items="{
    path : 'topmusics>/d/results',
    parameters : {  
        $top : '5'
    }}"
  class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
  <CustomListItem type="Navigation" press="onClick">
      <Link text="{topmusics>TITLE}"
            press="onClick" />
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

However, with this code I get the full music list and not just the top 5, which leads me to believe that since I have to pass "`/d/results`" the `xsodata` parameter (`"$top : '5'"`) is ignored. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

On a side node, I don't set the `"$top : '5'"` parameter on the `manifest.json` file because I also want to be able to use the same model  with other `xsodata` parameters.

Edit: Code of the controller:

```
onClick: function(oEvent) {
    var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.navTo("musicDetails", {
        musicPath: oItem.getBindingContext("topmusics").getPath().substr(11)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $top parameter in the binding parameters seems to be ignored by UI5. Also the documentation does not specify the existense of such a parameter. However there appears to be a undocumented property '**length**' which can be provided in the binding string.

> { path : '/Collection', length: 5 }

Also since you are using an OData service, it's ideal to use the OData model instead of the JSON model. The service URL should be upto the .xsodata path excluding the EntitySet(/Music_info).

So your manifest should look like this:

```
"topmusics": {
    "uri": "/path/to/odata/music.xsodata",
    "type": "OData"
}
```

And your XML will be set like this

```
<List headerText="Top 5 Musics" 
  items="{
  path : 'topmusics>/Music_info',
  length : 5
  }"
 class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
 <CustomListItem type="Navigation" press="onClick">
     <Link text="{topmusics>TITLE}"
           press="onClick" />
 </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/54e0ddf695af4a6c978472cecb01c64d.html
Setting the bindings this way, I can set the odata parameters, as I have in my code

Comment: That is the OData model V4 syntax and may not apply to the lower OData V2 Model which you you must be using in your case.

Comment: I see, although I find it strange that these parameters work when passed within the URL. Anyways, I applied your suggestions, but since I'm performing a navigation to another page when clicking on an element of the list, I get the error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined", when changing the model to OData. I wonder if there are options for parameters such as $orderby, $expand or $filter, or if using them in the URL is the only way.

Comment: The $filter & $orderby parameters are automatically created when you add fillters & sorters as defined [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/ec79a5d5918f4f7f9cbc2150e66778cc.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for. I added the code of the controller to the post. When I change the type of the model to OData I get that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" error, when trying to get the path to navigate to the detail page. Do you have any suggestion what might be wrong?

Comment: When you are finding the path, how do you try to get it ? Also the path you use should be "/Music_info('10020')" instead of "/odata/music.xsodata/Music_info('10020')".

Comment: I do oItem.getBindingContext("topmusics").getPath().substr(11) to get the position in the list of the item that was clicked

Comment: what is the string you get without the substring function?

Comment: I get "/Movie_info('10020')". I also edited the substring function to substr(1)., to just skip the '/', but either way I get the error that I mentioned.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a typo when reconstructing the path at the details page. Solved it and it's working. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136766/discussion-between-fc67-and-stephen-s).